# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

On deploying an Azure function, I see the following exception in Application Insights:

[image]

I have the following in config setting:

[image]

The key vault contains the service bus connection string:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the connection string is valid? Could you share your `appsetting.json` file? And sometimes reopen the visual studio can fix the issue.

Comment: @user989988 -Two questions - 1) How you reading this configuration setting in your code? 2) Check if keyvault reference is resolved. For that go to Kudu -> appsettings- > this will open a new tab in browser with all the settings; if you setting is resolved then should be should be having the secret value and if not then reference like `@Microsoft.KeyVault......`. If not resolved, then your function's system identity is not added into keyvaullt.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure any environment variable you read (like `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")`) has value in Azure App Service settings.

Publish tab > hosting section > ... > Manage Azure App Service settings > check if any key doesn't have value

[image: publish tab]

[image: app settings]

Comment: mainly to make sure the REMOTE have values

Comment: In my case I was missing Application Settings in the creation of a new environment.  In the Function App go to Configuration under settings and then validate that all Application Settings your function is expecting are set and set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can check :

1. If we are using any connection endpoint and reading the value from the appsettings. If yes, check the value of that settings.
2. Please confirm whether we are using a valid service bus connection endpoint in this case. ( if there is any)

These are very generic explanation for the problem statement as that doesn't provide more details. In case of functions many a times we see this error because if the connection string value is read from Azure Key Vault and you miss out on setting this value in the app settings of Azure Function configuration. In this scenario, an Access Policy created in the Key Vault configuration so that Azure Function application can read the values from the Key Vault. So you need to reverify the access policies to make sure the app settings values of the keys have valid values.